# Why previous stage is being called again while executing next stage in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am observing the previous stage is being called while executing the next stage, not sure what is wrong here with my jenkinsfile

Followed this documentation :

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline

```
pipeline { 
  agent none

  options {
    gitLabConnection('MY_CONNECTION')
  }

  stages {

    stage('scm_checkout') {
      agent { 
        label 'win_64'
      } 
      steps{
        deleteDir()
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',branches:[[name: '*/master']] 
        bat 'python -u repo/Jenkins_Scripts/createZip.py'
      }
    }

    stage('scm_build') {
      agent { 
        label 'win_64'
      } 
      steps{
        bat 'python -u repo/Jenkins_Scripts/build.py'
      }
    }
  } // end of stages

}
```

Output

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (scm_checkout)
[Pipeline] node
Running on xxxxxx in C:\jennew\workspace\PCQG-Pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] checkout
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] deleteDir
[Pipeline] checkout
Cloning the remote Git repository

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (scm_build)
[Pipeline] node
Running on xxxxxx in C:\jennew\workspace\PCQG-Pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] checkout
Cloning the remote Git repository
```

Likewise, this clones repository again and again with every stage. Not sure where I am committing a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you do here is slightly confusing. This is a `Jenkinsfile` right? So agent by default would do checkout on it's own. The stages are not being called from each other.

To turn that off you would need to add this to your agent part:

```
options { skipDefaultCheckout() }
```

Comment: Thank You,  this helps!

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer that works for you.